# strange symbol in firefox tab

Tags: firefox

I have been using firefox for quite sometime and today I suddenly started seeing a "yellow shield symbol" in some of my tabs. I am not sure what I might have done to cause this.

Please look at the attached image:

[image]

I could remove the icons by right clicking on the tab and un-checking the "Protect Tab" option. what I wanted to know is if this happens automatically or is there a shortcut key to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That seems to be a feature added by the Tab Mix Plus add-on.

See: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/internet/firefox/when-to-use-protect-tab-vs-lock-tab-in-firefox/